# I am constantly getting error for this code cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am using node js package express js to store user input data and return username stored after user click submit button.

Server Error (http://localhost:3000/store-user):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

For app.js file :

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

//Change it to javascript object
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Get request that send by browser
app.get('/currentime', function(req,res) {
    res.send('<h1>'+ new Date().toISOString() +'</h1>');

});  //localhost:3000/currenttime

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('<form action="/store-user" method="POST"><label>Your Name</label><input type="text" name="username"><button>Submit</button></form>');
})//localhost:3000/

app.post('/store-user', function(res,req) {
    const userName = req.body.username;
    console.log(userName);
    res.send('<h1>Username stored!</h1>');
});


app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: You've reversed your parameters for the callback on your `POST /store-user` route - they should be `req, res`, not `res, req` - you're inadvertently accessing the incorrect objects for what you're trying to do. [This Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/FluffyFamousBug#index.js) demonstrates that this fixes your code to execute as intended. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion fixed the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
req.body?.username
```

This code save your error but not a good solution.

```
app.post('/store-user', function(res,req) {
/* username field not set and so show error. Please check your request */
const userName = req.body.username;
console.log(userName);
res.send('<h1>Username stored!</h1>'); });
```